# sudo with tee displays staircase

Tags: command-line, 22.04, sudo, pipe, tee

Previously I ran without `sudo` and used `tee` to display on terminal and log to file:

```
./my_app | tee path/to/log_file
```

Now I need `sudo`:

```
sudo ./my_app | tee path/to/log_file
```

However, because of `tee` when I add `sudo` my output has weird diagonal offsets:

```
start of line 1 this is a test
        start of line 1 this is a test
                start of line 1 this is a test
                         start of line 1 this is a test
```

**It happens after I ask the user to enter input on the command line (press ENTER).**

It never happened without `sudo` or `tee`. Is there a way to use both together?

Comment: Related?: https://askubuntu.com/q/1459049/1004020 https://askubuntu.com/q/1458458/1004020

Answer (score 5):

#### Documentation

This likely is due to incorrect newline translation by your terminal and I guess that you don't see that behavior written into the log file you use but rather you see normal lines instead ... That is because terminals do post output processing before printing the output and that includes among other things translating `LF` to `CRLF` i.e. newline to carriage-return in order to bring each consecutive new line of output to the far left side of the terminal screen.

Post output processing should be enabled by default, but you can explicitly enable it with `stty opost` and you can reproduce what you see if you disable output post processing like so:

```
$ stty -opost; seq 3; stty opost
1
 2
  3
   $
```

... or you can reproduce it by only turning off terminal's output `LF` to `CRLF` translation `onlcr` like so:

```
$ stty -onlcr; seq 3; stty onlcr
1
 2
  3
   $
```

So, you could enable those two explicitly like:

```
$ stty opost onlcr; seq 3
1
2
3
$
```

... to fix that.

Notice that sometimes other terminal line printing settings might be involved in that and you might want to give combined settings like `-nl` a try ... To see current settings in your terminal, run `stty -a` like so:

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

... See [`man stty`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/stty.1.html) for more.

#### Discussion

What is the exact reason for that on your system? ... That can happen for a multitude of reasons and can only be traced on your system which I don't currently have hold of but, you do.

Why with `sudo` specifically? ... Well `sudo` gets its own terminal device "pseudo" (mainly to receive input for password … See https://askubuntu.com/a/1449987 ) while it's running your script (*especially if it runs in its own shell like when you run your script with `sudo` without specifying its `-b, --background` option*):

```
$ sudo tty; tty
/dev/pts/1
/dev/pts/0
$
```

What does that mean? It means this:

```
$ { sudo sh -c 'stty -onlcr; seq 3'; seq 4 6; } | tee file
1
 2
  3
   4
5
6
$
$
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

... notice disabling `onlcr` under `sudo` doesn't affect the current terminal's commands output printing but affects those in `sudo`'s ... Also notice that the same output written to the file is not affected as, in reality and in its essence, it's the same:

```
$ cat -A file
1$
2$
3$
4$
5$
6$
```

#### Your use case

> It happens after I ask the user to enter input on the command line
> (press ENTER).

... yes, it does:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'for i in 1 2 3; do read -t1; echo "$i"; done' | tee
1
 2
  3
   $
```

... but, starting from the version of `sudo` used on Ubuntu 23.10, this particularity seems to be [fixed](https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/releases/tag/SUDO_1_9_14p2) (this seems to only affect output when it's sent to a none tty e.g. a pipe ... See [source code](https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/commit/d821e8da3bd94f6315f6f8d8b1150ec3eb930c04#)) ... Special thanks to [@DanielT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1503089/sudo-with-tee-displays-staircase#comment2636265_1503146) for testing and bringing it to my attention.

Comment: The last version your `{ sudo sh -c 'stty -onlcr; seq 3'; seq 4 6; } | tee file` example is reproducible in is 23.04. On my 23.10 and the future 24.04, all numbers are left-aligned. Perhaps this was fixed in the meantime

Comment: @DanielT That is interesting as the providing binary package changed to [`sudo-ldap`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/mantic/+package/sudo-ldap) on 23.10 and it was [`sudo`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+package/sudo) on earlier releases ... I will try to look at differences between the two when I have time.

Comment: @DanielT Yep, check the second fix here: https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/releases/tag/SUDO_1_9_14p2 … That seems what the OP actually exactly has … I will update the answer for that later … Thanks for your testing which lead to the culprit in the specific use case described in OP … Well done Daniel :-)